#  User Controls hide and show

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a couple of user controls, which I show in my main form.

So let's say here's what i want:

```
Sub Show_Control1()
UserControl1.Show
'CODE TO HIDE EVERY OTHER DISPLAYED USER CONTROL ON THE MAIN FORM
End sub
```

right now I have to hide them one by one with hide, because I don't know what's the current displayed form.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "Visual Basic.NET -" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your situation on a Windows Forms application (.NET 4) and the following worked. I'm not sure why your way of using `GetType(T1) Is GetType(T2)` isn't working (maybe it has different semantics, like it doesn't consider inheritance) but you can use this instead:

```
Sub Show1()
    For Each ctrl As Control In Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is UserControl Then
            ctrl.Hide()
        End If
    Next
    UserControl11.Show()
End Sub
```

**Update:**

I checked the MSDN to see why is your code not working. Firstly the `TypeOf .. Is` operator is the one used to check for whether a type of an object is compatible with another. Here's what they MSDN article at (Link: [TypeOf keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5kz7s8h%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) says:

> The TypeOf keyword introduces a comparison clause that tests whether an object is derived from or implements a particular type, such as an interface.

However you're using the Is keyword (very different from that used in C# to check whether an object is of some particular type). The "Is" keyword is used to check whether two references reference the same object. Here's what MSDN at (Link: [Is keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)) says:

> [Is] Compares two object reference variables.

So I was right: you're using an operator with different semantics than your intentions. I rarely write VB .NET code these days. Nice question.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub Show_Control1()
For Each cont In Me.Controls
    cont.Hide
Next cont
UserControl1.Show
End sub
```

This will basically hide all controls, and then show just the one you want. Faster and simpler than checking on each control if it's not the one you want to stay visible.

Comment: Exactly what I want, BUT i have got a lot of User Controls.But it doesn't work with "gettype is usercontrol", it works with "gettype is USERCONTROLNAME" and i have a lot of forms!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Can you explain a little bit?

Comment: Well I have 2 User Controls - TestUserControl And User Control1. I Use "ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(UserControl)" to hide only the user control forms, because your code hides everything. But i can't just type "ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(UserControl)" and hide them all, like I do with TxtBoxes. I must write "ctrl.GetType() Is GetType(UserControlNAME)", so it's the same!

Comment: So this does what you want or not? I still don't quite understand :)

Comment: Partially.It's possible to do it with this, but i still have to hide them one by one!

Comment: Is "If TypeOf control Is TextBox Then ..." not working for what you need?